How to compute confidence and uncertainity of model without ground truth from softmax output?
Suppose I have 3 classes A,B,C.
Performing:
y_pred = model.predict(X) # suppose X only two sampel

Returning vector with length 2 aka shape (2,3), that still in probability format (no argmax).
y_pred -> [
  {A:0.2, B:0.3, C:0.5}, 
  {A:0.7, B:0.2, C:0.1}
]

I would define model that not confidence means, predicted class by model returning confidence value that closer to 1/N where N is num of classes (because it's not true and not false, it's not asserting false aka zero or asserting true aka one). But perhaps, there is another better definition, than mine. I still expect it returns scalar value for both uncertainty and confidence.
If my mine is the best definition, then I want to get summary of overall confidence predicted by model into scalar value using my definition.
So, what is the operation or aggregation technique to get the confidence and uncertainty of prediction where it has magnitude with range $[0,1]$?

I guess this is just a measure of confidence, right, regardless of whether or not that confidence is warranted (if the confident predictions are close to being correct)?

@Dave Yes, since there is no ground truth involved. No warranty and no correlation of how the confidence model prediction will resulting better performance.

I think, then, that this becomes a matter of calculating overall variance of a multinomial distribution, yes?

As far as I can tell, you don't offer any definition of "confidence," so let's begin there: please tell us what you mean by that term.

@whuber Confidence means, aggregation of the softmax output. In this case, I'm using mean(most_maximum-second_maximum) as the aggregation.

@Dave I'm not really understand about multinomial distribution.

While the uncertainty (or assertion) means, deviation of the softmax output distribution. [0.5,0.49,0.01] gives lower uncertainty compared to [0.5,0.125,0.125].

First, this is a truly unusual--perhaps unique--use of the word "confidence" and is sure to mislead all readers.  Second, "aggregation" is not something that lends itself to quantification, making it difficult to determine what you're doing or what you're asking.

@whuber Okay I will replace confidence as optimism. Aggregation might be replaced with amplitude or something.

Just replacing words, although helpful for for avoiding confusing language, is unlikely to clarify what you're doing.  Indeed, without providing a clear meaning for "overall confidence," it is impossible to understand your question.

@whuber At the end, I simply want to explain the blackbox inference by AI for the stakeholder. So that's why I need XAI

@MuhammadIkhwanPerwira While I believe my answer to be an extremely reasonable way to measure model confidence that is both theoretically grounded and consistent with your ideas about which sets of predictions are confident vs which are less confident, XAI seems to be a different subject (perhaps equally or even more useful to your work, but different, nonetheless).

I have (temporarily) deleted my answer while I think about how the dependence between categories factors into this and if you should be calculating the determinant of a whole covariance matrix for the multinomial distribution.

Perhaps there is relationship with Dirichlet distribution.

Maybe this is why my visualization looks like triangle due to Dirichlet by nature?

I don’t see the triangle, but that sounds reasonable to me. @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira

Answer:
Given a softmax output with an arbitrary number of classes $N$ for $N\geq2$, we can compute its confidence $c$ and uncertainty $u$ from its probability distribution $P$.

For the confidence: $ c = \frac{NP_{max}-1}{N-1} $

For the uncertainty:
$u = 1-\frac{P_{min}}{\frac{1-P_{max}}{N-1}}$


Where $0<=(u,c)<=1$, representing confidence and uncertainty magnitude.

Explanation
For the confidence, it's straightforward to take the maximum value of the distribution. Except it needs to be normalized relative to the mean of the value, and that's it has a range of $0<=c<=1$.
For the uncertainty, find the maximum value, and then find its relative uniform so that it can be compared with its minimum.
Let $P=[P_{max},P_1, P_2, ...,P_n]$. To find the relative uniform value, we must treat $P_1=P_2=...=P_n$.
As the probability distribution summation always leads to $1$. We get: $P_{max} + (N-1)P_n=1$ And so that relative uniform value is
$P_n = \frac{1-P_{max}}{N-1} $. Now we can compare its relative uniform value with its minimum.
Treating $P_{min}$ as a dividend and $P_n$ as a divisor, returning a value that has a range of $0<=u<=1$. This value is almost what I expect, except the higher uncertainty should go to $1$, while the lower uncertainty should go to $0$, and therefore inverting it results in $1-\frac{P_{min}}{P_n}$.

Example Output and Visualization:
Here is some possible output with $N=3$.
Out0 [0.99  0.005 0.005]: Confidence: 0.98, Uncertainty: 0.00
Out1 [0.8 0.1 0.1]: Confidence: 0.70, Uncertainty: -0.00
Out2 [0.5  0.25 0.25]: Confidence: 0.25, Uncertainty: 0.00
Out3 [0.33 0.33 0.33]: Confidence: -0.00, Uncertainty: 0.01
Out4 [0.99  0.009 0.001]: Confidence: 0.98, Uncertainty: 0.80
Out5 [0.8  0.19 0.01]: Confidence: 0.70, Uncertainty: 0.90
Out6 [0.5  0.49 0.01]: Confidence: 0.25, Uncertainty: 0.96
Out7 [0.1  0.45 0.45]: Confidence: 0.18, Uncertainty: 0.64

Preprocessing visualization with scaling from $[0,1]$ into $[-1,1]$ results in four quadrants that what model might say based on its softmax output:


Could you explain how/why you asked and answered your question?

I asked my question because to get the insight of reasoning of deep learning model inference so that it can be explained for the stakeholder or domain specific expert, mainly for medical diagnoses that carefully to decide. I answered it because it has not been answered for day. How I answered it, simply click the add answer button, then type with keyboard.

Makes sense! I appreciate your response
